# RFCOMM Bluetooth in ruby (linux)

Tags: ruby, linux, bluetooth, rubygems

I am trying to find a gem/library that has RFCOMM and other bluetooth access on linux through bluez or other means. I am trying to port a python server that interacts with a piece of hardware (https://code.google.com/p/adqmisc/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fliveview) although I can not seem to find any decent bluetooth support for ruby.

I found this: https://github.com/cfiorini/rbluez although it is not in the gem repository so I don't know how to install it. It seems to have basic RFCOMM support and HCI support which seems to be all I need in order to port the project.

So is there any good ruby gems that wrap around RFCOMM/HCI to allow access to a bluetooth adapter on linux?

Thank you.

How would I go about installing that rbluez library which is not in the gems repository?
Or is it possible to initiate a bluetooth socket as you can in C with AF_BLUETOOTH? If so would this done with a client/server example.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the [rbluez](https://github.com/cfiorini/rbluez) code by creating your own gem. That's easy but it may take you one or a couple of days to get used to it.

Follow the steps described [here](http://writehack.com/2011/1/30/Packaging%20a%20Ruby%20C%20Extension%20as%20a%20Gem) to create the gem and replace the appropriate files with the ones supplied by rbluez's repository (i.e. extconf.rb and rbluez.c).

I don't guarantee rbluez will compile on your system (you'll have to check dependencies, if any) but I can assure the process described by the steps I linked above work to successfully create your gem.